# How do you resize an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have a HTML editor that inserts items from predefined buttons using javascript and would like add a button to be able to post a thumbnail of a downloaded image with a link to view it full size. I have created the following code but it doesn't work and always inserts a 100X100 size image. Can anyone suggest a better way that does work?

```
    // insert HTML code
insertHtml: function (url, title) {
    var imgHeight;
    var imgWidth;
    function setHTMLImageSize() {
        imgHeight = this.height;
        imgWidth = this.width;
        var ImageRatio = (imgHeight / imgWidth);
        if (imgWidth > 100) {
            imgWidth = 100;
            imgHeight = (imgWidth * ImageRatio);
        }
        return true;
    }
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.name = url;
    myImage.onload = setHTMLImageSize;
    myImage.src = url;
    if (imgWidth = 0) {
        imgWidth = 100;
    }
    if (imgHeight = 0) {
        imgHeight = 100;
    }
    this.get_designPanel().insertHTML("<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"" + "_blank" + "\" style=\"" + "text-decoration: none" + "\" ><img src=\"" + url + "\" title=\"" + title + "\" width=\"" + imgWidth + "\" height=\"" + imgHeight + "\" /></a><br/>click image to View full size<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting width and height to 100 before the onload function has fired. The onload will happen asynchronously so you should do a check for zero height or width inside the callback.

Edit:-
As observed by enhzflep in the comment below you have also used equal as assignment rather than to check conditions. I'd change them to triple equals === as a rule when you know the type you are expecting.

Is it not going to be simpler to control a thumbnail through CSS anyway? You could set max-height and max-width properties to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: Done with the OnLoad event SetHTMLImageSize call

Comment: @DavidDIlley - Yes, kindof. That call affects the image in your code known as `myImage`. This call to `SetHTMLImageSize` alters the values that `imgWidth` and `imgHeight`. Unfortunately, these are used before they're given a value. The run through the code sees them both holding nothing (not zero, but nothing - i.e `undefined`) Furthermore, in the call where you check to see if they're zero, you've mistakenly used `=` (set to) rather than `==` (is equal to). Add some calls to `console.log` and you'll see that the code doesn't execute in the order you appear to think it does.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing the single = out ... I missed that ... 

I could use a CSS if I just wanted to set the "thumbnail" image to a predefined size but I am actually trying to scale the image and still maintain the original width to height ratio using a maximum width so it is not distorted ...

Comment: From what you said it appears since the call to set the height and width variables is asynchronous there is no way to load an image, get the actual width and height values, and then insert HTML with a ratio of real image's width and height size variables in javascript. 
Since the image must fit in a window that is only 200px wide at this point I guess I will have to set it to a predefined size that fits and not worry about it being distorted ... I guess users can click on the 100X100  "thumbnail" image in the small windows to see it it in a separate window with it's actual ratio dimensions.

Comment: Excuse me ... I missed the part about setting the CSS to maintain aspect ratio ... I am not familiar with that process ... would that be like the following:

.resizewithratio

{

    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: @David Dilley you can achieve it asynchronously but you will notice a delay until the image is loaded. Using CSS max-width and max-height will allow an element to scale up to those dimensions until the first dimension meets that criteria. If you set width: 100px the width will always be 100 and the height will scale. If your images are all the same orientation,  this might look good enough. But I'd go with the max- CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone ... from the CSS suggestion I have resolved the issue by removing all the code to determine the image size and instead including a style attribute setting the width to 100 and the height to auto into the HTML image code being added to the editor ... see below

```
        this.get_designPanel().insertHTML("<br/>Thumbnail view<br/><a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"" + "_blank" + "\" style=\"" + "text-decoration: none;" + "\" ><img style=\"" + "width: 100px; height: auto" + "\" src=\"" + url + "\" alt=\"" + title + "\" title=\"" + title + "\" /></a><br/>Click image to view in seperate window<br/>");
```

Comment: I forgot about images that might be under 100 pixels wide ... the above code will actually enlarge an image the user inserts if it is under 100 pixels wide ... guess this will work for now but I am still looking for a way to scale the image only if it is over 100 pixels wide :)